# Zend Framework Custom Action Helper fails

Tags: zend-framework, action, helper

I am trying to create a custom Action Helper in ZF. I have read the docs, and googled for help, but I can't get this working.

Here's relevant code from Bootstrap.php (including everything I've tried to get this working):

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoLoader=Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $resourceLoader=new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath'=>APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace'=>'',
        'resourceTypes'=>array(                
            'models'=>array(
                'path'=>'models/',
                'namespace'=>'Model_'
             ),  
             'forms'=>array(
                'path'=>'forms/',
                'namespace'=>'Form_'
             ),
             'helpers'=>array(
                 'path'->'../library/My/Action/Helpers/',
                 'namespace'->'My_Action_Helpers_'
             ),
         )
     ));

     $autoLoader->pushAutoloader($resourceLoader);

     Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(new My_Action_Helpers_Detect()); 
}
```

Here's where I declare my helper in library/My/Action/Helpers/Detect.php:

```
class Detect extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    private $_agents = array('safari', 'msie', 'chrome', 'firefox', 'opera');

    public function direct($type) {
        $type = strtolower($type);

        if(!in_array($type, $this->_agents)) return false;

        return substr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), $type);
    }  
}
```

(And BTW, I know I'd be better off using Zend_Http_UserAgent, but I don't have access to my php.ini file)

And here's where I initialize the  helper from my controller:

```
init()
{
...
        //$this->_userAgentHelper = $this->_helper->getHelper('UserAgentDetect');
...
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Cannot redeclare class Detect in /var/www/html/dev/library/My/Action/Helpers/Detect.php

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on here. Do you have another class called 'Detect' in your app or is it including the same file twice? The init function you've posted does nothing.

Comment: Also, since the helper is in your library folder you shouldn't need to setup a new resource type for it (as long as your library folder is on the include path and 'My_' is a registered namespace). But to follow the convention the class name should be `My_Action_Helpers_Detect`.

Comment: @TimFountain and as far as I know, method name shoud be not `direct()` but `detect()` too.

Comment: No, `direct()` is correct (although optional) for action helpers. You're thinking of view helpers which have to have a method matching the class name.

Comment: @Tim, I was using the wrong class name. I changed it per your suggestion and it worked Thank you.

Comment: @TimFountain Add the solution as answer so Barbara can mark it as correct and close this question.